# How to group categories in a variable using numpy and dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, data-manipulation

I want to group multiple categories in a pandas variable using numpy.where and dictionary.

Currently I am trying this using just numpy.where which increases my code a lot if I have a lot of categories. I want to create a map using dictionary and then use that map in numpy.where .

Sample Data frame:

```py
dataF = pd.DataFrame({'TITLE':['CEO','CHIEF EXECUTIVE','EXECUTIVE OFFICER','FOUNDER',
                 'CHIEF OP','TECH OFFICER','CHIEF TECH','VICE PRES','PRESIDENT','PRESIDANTE','OWNER','CO OWNER',
                 'DIRECTOR','MANAGER',np.nan]})
```

```py
dataF
    TITLE
0   CEO
1   CHIEF EXECUTIVE
2   EXECUTIVE OFFICER
3   FOUNDER
4   CHIEF OP
5   TECH OFFICER
6   CHIEF TECH
7   VICE PRES
8   PRESIDENT
9   PRESIDANTE
10  OWNER
11  CO OWNER
12  DIRECTOR
13  MANAGER
14  NaN
```

Numpy operation

```py
dataF['TITLE_GRP'] = np.where(dataF['TITLE'].isna(),'NOTAVAILABLE',
                     np.where(dataF['TITLE'].str.contains('CEO|CHIEF EXECUTIVE|EXECUTIVE OFFICER|FOUN'),'CEO_FOUNDER',
                     np.where(dataF['TITLE'].str.contains('CHIEF|OFFICER|^CFO$|^COO$|^CIO$|^CTO$|^CMO$'),'OTHER_OFFICERS',
                     np.where(dataF['TITLE'].str.contains('VICE|VP'),'VP',
                     np.where(dataF['TITLE'].str.contains('PRESIDENT|PRES'),'PRESIDENT',
                     np.where(dataF['TITLE'].str.contains('OWNER'),'OWNER_CO_OWN',
                     np.where(dataF['TITLE'].str.contains('MANAGER|GM|MGR|MNGR|DIR|HEAD|CHAIR'),'DIR_MGR_HEAD'
                     ,dataF['TITLE'])))))))
```

Transformed Data

```py
    TITLE   TITLE_GRP
0   CEO CEO_FOUNDER
1   CHIEF EXECUTIVE CEO_FOUNDER
2   EXECUTIVE OFFICER   CEO_FOUNDER
3   FOUNDER CEO_FOUNDER
4   CHIEF OP    OTHER_OFFICERS
5   TECH OFFICER    OTHER_OFFICERS
6   CHIEF TECH  OTHER_OFFICERS
7   VICE PRES   VP
8   PRESIDENT   PRESIDENT
9   PRESIDANTE  PRESIDENT
10  OWNER   OWNER_CO_OWN
11  CO OWNER    OWNER_CO_OWN
12  DIRECTOR    DIR_MGR_HEAD
13  MANAGER DIR_MGR_HEAD
14  NaN NOTAVAILABLE
```

What I want to do is create some mapping like below:

```py
TITLE_REPLACE = {'CEO_FOUNDER':'CEO|CHIEF EXECUTIVE|EXECUTIVE OFFICER|FOUN',
                'OTHER_OFFICERS':'CHIEF|OFFICER|^CFO$|^COO$|^CIO$|^CTO$|^CMO$',
                'VP':'VICE|VP',
                'PRESIDENT':'PRESIDENT|PRES',
                'OWNER_CO_OWN':'OWNER',
                'DIR_MGR_HEAD':'MANAGER|GM|MGR|MNGR|DIR|HEAD|CHAIR'}
```

And then feed it to some function which applies the stepwise numpy operation and gives me the same result as above.

I am doing this I have to parameterize my code in such a way that all parameter for data manipulation will be provided from a json file.

I was trying pandas.replace as it has dictionary capability but it doesnt preserve the hiercichal structure as done in nested np.where, its also not able to replace the whole title as it just replaces the string when it finds a match.

In case you are able to provide solution for above I would also like to know how to solve following 2 other scenario:

1. This scenario contains .isin operation instead of regex

```py
dataF['INDUSTRY'] = np.where(dataF['INDUSTRY'].isin(['AEROSPACE','AGRICULTURE/MINING','EDUCATION','ENERGY']),'AER_AGR_MIN_EDU_ENER',
                    np.where(dataF['INDUSTRY'].isin(['TRAVEL','INSURANCE','GOVERNMENT','FINANCIAL SERVICES','AUTO','PHARMACEUTICALS']),'TRA_INS_GOVT_FIN_AUT_PHAR',
                    np.where(dataF['INDUSTRY'].isin(['BUSINESS GOODS/SERVICES','CHEMICALS ','TELECOM','TRANSPORTATION']),'BS_CHEM_TELE_TRANSP',
                    np.where(dataF['INDUSTRY'].isin(['CONSUMER GOODS','ENTERTAINMENT','FOOD AND BEVERAGE','HEALTHCARE','INDUSTRIAL/MANUFACTURING','TECHNOLOGY']),'CG_ENTER_FB_HLTH_IND_TECH',
                    np.where(dataF['INDUSTRY'].isin(['ADVERTISING','ASSOCIATION','CONSULTING/ACCOUNTING','PUBLISHING/MEDIA','TECHNOLOGY']),'ADV_ASS_CONS_ACC_PUBL_MED_TECH',
                    np.where(dataF['INDUSTRY'].isin(['RESTAURANT','SOFTWARE']),'REST_SOFT',
                                            'NOTAVAILABLE'))))))
```

2. This scenario contains .between operation

```py
dataF['annual_revn'] = np.where(dataF['annual_revn'].between(1000000,10000000),'1_10_MILLION',
                       np.where(dataF['annual_revn'].between(10000000,15000000),'10_15_MILLION',
                       np.where(dataF['annual_revn'].between(15000000,20000000),'15_20_MILLION',
                       np.where(dataF['annual_revn'].between(20000000,50000000),'20_50_MILLION',
                       np.where(dataF['annual_revn'].between(50000000,1000000000),'50_1000_MILLION',
                                           'NOTAVAILABLE_OUTLIER')))))
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that your TITLE_REPLACE dict keys are formatted as they are? Instead of having "," between the keys?

Comment: @BenPap I was thinking of using TITLE_REPLACE dict values in the numpy.where and replacing matching rows with the keys. Its just and idea the key value pair can be reversed. I have given "," after each key value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below method works, but it isn't particularly elegant, and it may not be that fast.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

dataF = pd.DataFrame({'TITLE':['CEO','CHIEF EXECUTIVE','EXECUTIVE OFFICER','FOUNDER',
                 'CHIEF OP','TECH OFFICER','CHIEF TECH','VICE PRES','PRESIDENT','PRESIDANTE','OWNER','CO OWNER',
                 'DIRECTOR','MANAGER',np.nan]})

TITLE_REPLACE = {'CEO_FOUNDER':'CEO|CHIEF EXECUTIVE|EXECUTIVE OFFICER|FOUN',
                'OTHER_OFFICERS':'CHIEF|OFFICER|^CFO$|^COO$|^CIO$|^CTO$|^CMO$',
                'VP':'VICE|VP',
                'PRESIDENT':'PRESIDENT|PRES',
                'OWNER_CO_OWN':'OWNER',
                'DIR_MGR_HEAD':'MANAGER|GM|MGR|MNGR|DIR|HEAD|CHAIR'}

# Swap the keys and values from the raw data, and split regex by '|'
reverse_replace = {}
for key, value in TITLE_REPLACE.items():
    for value_single in value.split('|'):
        reverse_replace[value_single] = key

def mapping_func(x):
    if not x is np.nan:
        for key, value in reverse_replace.items():
            if re.compile(key).search(x):
                return value
    return 'NOTAVAILABLE'

dataF['TITLE_GRP'] = dataF['TITLE'].apply(mapping_func)


                TITLE       TITLE_GRP
0                 CEO     CEO_FOUNDER
1     CHIEF EXECUTIVE     CEO_FOUNDER
2   EXECUTIVE OFFICER     CEO_FOUNDER
3             FOUNDER     CEO_FOUNDER
4            CHIEF OP  OTHER_OFFICERS
5        TECH OFFICER  OTHER_OFFICERS
6          CHIEF TECH  OTHER_OFFICERS
7           VICE PRES              VP
8           PRESIDENT       PRESIDENT
9          PRESIDANTE       PRESIDENT
10              OWNER    OWNER_CO_OWN
11           CO OWNER    OWNER_CO_OWN
12           DIRECTOR    DIR_MGR_HEAD
13            MANAGER    DIR_MGR_HEAD
14                NaN    NOTAVAILABLE
```

For your additional scenario, it may make sense to construct a df with the industry mapping data, then do `df.merge` to determine the grouping from the industry